# how do i insert html file that have hebrew text and read it back in sql server 2008 using the filestream option?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2008, filestream, hebrew

i am new to the filestream option in sql server 2008,
but i have already understand how to open this option and how to create a table that allow you to save files. 
let say my table contains:
id,name, filecontent

i tried to insert an html file (that has hebrew chars/text in it) to this table.
i'm writing in asp.net (c#), using visual studio 2008.

but when i tried to read back the content , hebrew char becomes '?'.

the actions i took were:

### 1. i read the file like this:

```
        // open the stream reader
        System.IO.StreamReader aFile = new StreamReader(FileName,   System.Text.UTF8Encoding.UTF8);

        // reads the file to the end
        stream = aFile.ReadToEnd();

        // closes the file
        aFile.Close();
```

### return stream; // returns the stream

2. i inserted the 'stream' to the filecontent column as binary data.
3. i tried to do a 'select' to this column and the data did return (after i coverted it back to string) but hebrew chars become '?'

how do i solve this problem ? 
what I should pay attention to ?

thanks, 
gadym

Answer (score 2):

I succeeded to solve this problem.
I was wrong , the problem wasnt in the sql server , but in my code, when i transfer it from binary to string and vice versa.

when you need to convert string (that have hebrew chars) to binary you can write the following lines:

```
System.Text.UTF8Encoding encoding = new System.Text.UTF8Encoding();
//HtmlFile = the file i read as string and now i want to convert it to bytes array.
byte[] ConvertTextToBytesArray = encoding.GetBytes(HtmlFile);
```

and vice versa :

```
    string str;
    System.Text.UTF8Encoding enc = new System.Text.UTF8Encoding();
    // result = the binary data i want to convert it back to string
    str = enc.GetString(result);
```

i used for some reason System.Text.ASCIIEncoding instead of System.Text.UTF8Encoding.

thank you Meff !

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the UTF8 encoding may not work with the Hebrew?

See here for an older discussion: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/csharplanguage/thread/73c81574-b434-461f-b766-fb9d0e4353c7

```
sr = new StreamReader(fs, Encoding.GetEncoding("windows-1255"));
```

Alternatively, are you sure the file is encoded in UTF8?

Also, FILESTREAM may actually perform worse if the BLOB is under 1MB, and HTML files I would expect to fit that description. Have you considered NVARCHAR(MAX) instead.

http://blogs.msdn.com/manisblog/archive/2007/10/21/filestream-data-type-sql-server-2008.aspx

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I must save those html files as files in my database and not as string or something like that. true, the file size is less than 1MB , even close to 2K, but i must save it as file. the type of the 'filecontent' column is varbinary(MAX). can i change it to NVARCHAR(MAX) and still it will behave as a file ?

Comment: @gadym, if you must save the files as FILESTREAM then they must be VARBINARY(MAX). Now VARBINARY does not know or care about text encoding, so the problem is your encoding method - Check the encoding of the HTML file, and try a different encoding as I mentioned above :)

Comment: thanks again.but unfortunately when i had changed the encoding as you mentioned,the hebrew becomes gibberish:).i tried to put also meta tag in the file like this:<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1255"> but only when i use the utf8 it's ok.but as i said before when i tries to 'select' the binary data and transfer it back to a string the hebrew chars becomes '???'.i had an idea-maybe i need to change the collation of the table/database? (i dont know how to do that so i didnt try it yet)is it related somehow ?hope you can/still have the energy to help me.:-|

Comment: @gadym, the database collation shouldn't matter for VARBINARY. Check the input on the way in, does it look OK after it's been read in from the stream but before it gets stored? How are you retrieving the data from the column?